# Custom column labels in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table:

[image]

I want to customize the column labels. eg: "b" column label should be "In Progress".

Please help me.

Comment: Type the value you want in the cell.

Comment: Or change it in the `Value Field Settings` drop down box option.

Comment: I don't see an option to edit it in the Value Field Settings. Could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

Select the data from which the pivot table is from

- highlight the column in which the "b" is in
- find and replace all the "b" with "In Progress"
- Update the Pivot table

OR

Copy the data from the pivot table and Paste it as text delimited I believe.
-Change the "b" to "In Progress"

Please respond if it isnt clear so I can go into further detail.
All the best

Comment: I cannot replace the source data. Also I want this pivot table for report purposes as I want to refresh the details everytime.